# can't run integrated WebLogic 12.2.1.4 server on Windows 10

Tags: oracle, java-8, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I have windows 10 machine, and JDeveloper 12.2.1.4.0 , when i try to run the weblogic server for the first time i get this error :

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Users\OSMOHAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_PT.12.2.1.4.0_GENERIC_190911.2248.S
Product Home:  D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\OSMOHAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2020-06-05 09:14:45

cmd.exe /c ""D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\OSMOHAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\OSMOHAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\OSMOHAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.wlst.ScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(ScriptRunnerImpl.java:106)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DomainScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(DomainScriptRunnerImpl.java:146)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder.createDomain(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:606)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder.build(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:274)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder$1.run(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:225)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed argument has embedded quote: "D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\OSMOHAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.needsEscaping(ProcessImpl.java:279)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.createCommandLine(ProcessImpl.java:202)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:436)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 9 more
```

i did some research and most people tell that the solution in the following url is fixing the problem

```
http://unversioned.blogspot.com/2015/12/jdeveloper-12c-generic-installer-cannot-create-weblogic-domain.html
```

but the problem is when i open the javashell.py file , i don't find an entry for

```
_osTypeMap =
```

it Doesn't Exist in the file

Also  , another solution the people said it worked is by adding this line

```
Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

but they didn't said where to add it and what is the exact steps !

Comment: Are there any executable files in directory `D:\Oracle\Middleware\BPM_12.4\oracle_common\common\bin`?

Comment: yes there is files of cmd and sh extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with JDeveloper, WLS 12.2.1.4 and JDK 8 opened at My Oracle Support : Bug 30670839 : INTEGRATED WLS CANNOT BE CREATED WHEN USING JDK1.8.0_231

There is no patch available for now but you can try the workaround provided in the bug note : Revert back to JDK shipped with JDeveloper

Comment: can you share the url for this bug , i've searched online and couldn't find it

Comment: This document is only accessible on My Oracle Support site and for this you need a support contract.

Comment: Make a seach in MOS with "Bug 30670839" you will get the document.

Comment: Can someone help how to revert the JDK to the one shipped with JDeveloper?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If we see, problem is with the type of command that JDeveloper executes to start the weblogic instance is old and therefore does not work correctly, however below solution is working. It did solve the issue in my machine

We must modify this file:

```
C:<JDEVELOPER Install Path>\ide\bin\ide.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
AddVMOption -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands = true
```

[image]
Post modification, save the file.
Restart the Jdeveloper, compile and launch the weblogic server.